# Group by and assign a value to list

Tags: c#, linq, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-multiselect

I have an stored procedure which brings the data in this fashion. I need this to be grouped and assigned to a list. How to do this?

```
+------------+---------+------------+------------+
|   RuleID   |RuleName | TemplateId |TemplateName|
+------------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1          | R1      |  1         | T1         |
| 1          | R1      |  2         | T2         |
| 1          | R1      |  3         | T3         |
| 1          | R1      |  4         | T4         |
| 2          | R2      |  1         | T1         |
| 2          | R2      |  2         | T2         |
+------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

My model looks something like this

```
public class MergeRulesGridModel
{
    public int RuleID { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public TemplateListModel TemplateList { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateListModel
{
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
}
```

As if now I'm assigning the values like this

```
public ActionResult ReadMergeRules([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    //Get 
    var siteList = _unitOfWork.EmailManagementRepository.GetMergeRulesAndStrategy().Select(t => new MergeRulesGridModel
    {
        RuleID = t.RuleID,
        RuleName = t.RuleName,
        TemplateList = new TemplateListModel { TemplateId = t.TemplateId, TemplateName = t.TemplateName }
    }).ToList();

    // Flatten the account to avoid circular references during JSON serialization
    DataSourceResult result = siteList.ToDataSourceResult(request, item => new
    {
        item.RuleID,
        item.RuleName,
        item.TemplateList
    });

    return Json(result);
}
```

And I'm showing the value in kendo grid in my view. I want to display the Template under a multiselect control. How can I group by and assign a value to List?

Comment: Have you tried the GroupBy query?

Comment: How would the output data model look like?

Comment: Vivek, How to use GroupBy here??

Comment: Yacoub, what do you mean by output data model?

Comment: How would the output data look like? Would the relationship between `MergeRulesGridModel` and `TemplateListModel` be 1 to1 as it is now? Or 1 to many?

Comment: Yacoub, as if now it is 1 to 1. That is where the problem is

Comment: @Sachinjeev, it is still not clear. Try to show a sample output in the question.